# Loading and drawing a bitmap on VGA in C

Tags: c, bitmap, vga

I´m trying to load and draw a 16 color bitmap on screen. I have a function for loading it and another for drawing the bitmap. However, when trying to draw the bitmap I´m getting all pixels in color white.

I think I might be having a problem with the color palette. Can anyone tell me if my palette information is correct or if there´s any problem with my loading or drawing method?

**Load Bitmap:**

```
typedef struct {
    word width;
    word height;
    byte pallete[256 * 3];
    byte *data;
} BITMAP;

/**************************************************************************
 *  load_bmp                                                              *
 *    Loads a bitmap file into memory.                                    *
 **************************************************************************/

void load_bmp(char *file, BITMAP *b) {      
    FILE *fp;
    long index;
    byte a;
    word num_colors;
    int x;
    //SetGfxMode(0x3);

    /* Opening file */
    if ((fp = fopen(file,"rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo %s.\n", file);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Validating if the image is a valid bitmap */
    if (fgetc(fp) != 'B' || fgetc(fp) != 'M') {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("%s is not a bitmap file. \n", file);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Height and width of the image */
    fskip(fp, 16);
    fread(&b->width, sizeof(word), 1, fp);
    fskip(fp, 2);
    fread(&b->height, sizeof(word), 1, fp);
    fskip(fp, 22);
    fread(&num_colors, sizeof(word), 1, fp);
    fskip(fp, 6);

    /* We are loading a 16 color image */
    if (num_colors == 0)
        num_colors = 16;

    /* Intentamos alojar memoria para la data del bitmap */
    if ((b->data = (byte *)malloc((word)(b->width * b->height))) == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error allocating memory for file %s.\n", file);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Reading palette info */
    for (index = 0; index < num_colors; index++) {
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+2)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+1)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+0)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        x = fgetc(fp);
    }

    /* Leyendo el bitmap */
    for (index = (b->height - 1) * b->width; index >= 0; index -= b->width) {
        for (x = 0; x < b->width; x++) {
            a = fgetc(fp);
            //printf("%d",a);
            //getch();
            b->data[(word)(index + x)] = a;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Draw Bitmap:**

```
/**************************************************************************
 *  draw_transparent_bitmap                                               *
 *    Draws a transparent bitmap.                                         *
 **************************************************************************/

void draw_transparent_bitmap(BITMAP *bmp, int x, int y) {
    int i, j;
    word bitmap_offset = 0;
    byte data;

    for (j = 0; j < bmp->height; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < bmp->width; i++, bitmap_offset++) {
            data = bmp->data[bitmap_offset];
            /* Pintando en pantalla */
            if (data)
                plot_pixel(x + i, j + y, data);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For more information: Im using 12h mode 16 color VGA:

this are my video_set and plot pixel functions:

```
void SetGfxMode(int mode)
{
    __dpmi_regs regs;
    memset(&regs,0, sizeof(regs));
    regs.x.ax=mode;
    //regs.x.ax=0xD; //screen mode (EGA)
    //regs.x.ax=0x13; //screen mode (VGA)
    __dpmi_int(0x10,&regs);
    //_farsetsel(_dos_ds);
    VGA=(byte *)0xA0000 + __djgpp_conventional_base;

    unsigned char weird_number=(SCREEN_WIDTH/8);
    for (int x=0; x<SCREEN_WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            setpixel_i[x][y] = y*weird_number + x/8; /* Memory Location */
        }
        setpixel_b[x] = (0x80)>>(x%8); /* compute Bit Mask */
    }


    return;
    }
```

**Plot Pixel:**

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
byte * VGA;
long int setpixel_i[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT];
unsigned char setpixel_b[SCREEN_WIDTH];
long int setpixel_ti;
byte double_buffer[SCREEN_SIZE];
unsigned char setpixel_tb;
void plot_pixel(int x, int y, int col) 
{ 
    #ifdef SCREEN_SAFE
        if ((x<0) && (x>=SCREEN_WIDTH) && (y<0) && (y>=SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        {return;}
    #endif
    //char far *screen = (char far *)0xA0000000; //djgpp doesn't understand far for some reason, maybe it's just me! heh
    //long int i;
    //unsigned char b;

    outp(0x3ce,0x05); /* Graphics Mode */ 
    outp(0x3cf,0x02); /* Write Mode 2 */ 

    setpixel_ti=setpixel_i[x][y];
    setpixel_tb=setpixel_b[x];
    //i = y*40 + x/8; /* Memory Location */
    //b = (0x80)>>(x%8); /* compute Bit Mask */

    outp(0x3ce,0x08); /* Bit Mask Register */ 
    outp(0x3cf,setpixel_tb); /* Bit Mask */
    outp(0x3ce,0x03); /* Function Select Register */ 
    outp(0x3cf,0x00); /* Replace Pixel */ 
    setpixel_tb = VGA[setpixel_ti]; /* Dummy Read to refresh latch registers (THIS IS *VERY* IMPORTANT)*/
    VGA[setpixel_ti] = col; /* Set Pixel */

}
```

**Set Pallete:**

```
void set_pallete(byte *pallete){
    int i;
    outp(PALETTE_INDEX,0);
    for(i=0;i<16*3;i++){
        outp(PALETTE_DATA,pallete[i]);

    }
}
```

**Fskip**

```
 void fskip(FILE *fp, int num_bytes){

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<num_bytes; i++){
            fgetc(fp);

    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
load_bmp("home16.bmp",&fondo_inicio);   
set_pallete(fondo_inicio.pallete);

draw_transparent_bitmap(&fondo_inicio,0,0);
```

Comment: A 16-color image would have 2 pixels per byte. Or are you talking about a 256-color image that only uses 16 colors? Also note that biClrUsed could be 0, in which case you'd use biBitCount to deduce the number of colors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not a code review or debugging service.

Comment: @Olaf there's an existing close reason that's applicable. "Questions asking *why isn't my code working?* should include a MCVE".

Comment: Why do you only plot non zero `data`?  Is color 0 supposed to be transparent?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, 0 is my defined transparent color.

Comment: @Olaf I´m sorry for doing that, I did not know I could not post this types of questions. It´s ok to close the question then.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Sure, but the one given is more specific, as OP clearly asks to review his code and find the problem. Feel free to close-vote for the other reason.

Comment: Is the bitmap a 256 color BITMAP with 1 byte per pixel?  If so, modify the question to clarify this.  Also you do not apply the palette anywhere, what is the prototype and semantics of `plot_pixel`?  How many bits for the third argument? what representation of colors?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question.  I don't see anywhere that you initialize the palette, nor do I see where you set the video mode.  That code could prove very useful.

Comment: The kind of problem is not OT per-se. Take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments. I added all the information you requested on the question. Im reading the How to Ask section too. Thanks @Olaf

Comment: Why not first try to simply put colored points or a line?

Comment: @Olaf I can already do that. I just did not included the line function since I did not considered it relevant to the question. However the plot_pixel function does work and it´s on the edits I made.

Comment: The function itself might not be relevant, bnut the information you tried and that it works very well is. For example it shows your palette is correct and you uise the correct memory, etc. - presuming your claim "does work" means you tested correctly.

Comment: Ok I´m sorry for forgetting the info. But yes, right now I can plot lines with different colors with no problem at all (I use random number between 0-15 for the colors). However when calling the draw bitmap I just get white pixels plotted on my screen.

Comment: please post info about the `fskip()` function.  I'm not finding it under ubuntu linux 14.04 with gcc compiler man pages.  Nor am I finding it via an online search.

Comment: in C, when calling the system memory allocation functions, do not cast the returned value.  The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, leads to misunderstandings, makes understanding, debug, maintenance much more difficult.  Note: `malloc()` expects a `size_t` not a `word` type for a parameter

Comment: the allocated memory for `data` must be such that each row is a multiple of `sizeof(long)`   which often means there are some padding bytes on the end of each row in the pixel map.

Comment: the posted code contains lots of 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much harder to read/understand.   Strongly suggest: use a `enum` to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  Some of the 'magic' numbers are: 16,2,22,6, 3, (256*3)

Comment: this line: `if ((x<0) && (x>=SCREEN_WIDTH) && (y<0) && (y>=SCREEN_HEIGHT))` seems to be incorrect.  `x` cannot be both <0 and >SCREEN_WIDTH.   Similar statement for `y`.   Perhaps you meant: `if ((x<0) || (x>=SCREEN_WIDTH) || (y<0) || (y>=SCREEN_HEIGHT))`

Comment: @user3629249 thanks that's an error I did not notice.

Comment: I finally was able to load a bmp. But it was a 256 color bmp. Somehow my functions work for those types of bmp. I´m now just dealing with the problem that it is being displayed at an offset of the position I give it. I tell it to draw at (0,0) it starts drawing the left half of the bmp on the right side and the right half of the bmp on the left side.